# Parameter estimation using maximum likleihood evaluation on "fit" residuals

Tags: maximum-likelihood, likelihood-ratio

Let's say I have some set of data $X$ which is dependant on some parameter $\theta$ which I want to find out. Let us also suppose that I have a good idea about the function (not a distribution) that describes the data $f(\theta)$.

Normally what I would do is a chi-square minimisation test. I generate multiple sets of $f(\theta)$ varying $\theta$ each time and perform my test by:
$$\chi^{2} = \sum_{i}^{N} (X_{i} - f(\theta)_{i})^{2}$$
I then end up with a $\chi^{2}$ for every value of $\theta$, i.e. $ \chi^{2}(\theta)$ and where $ \chi^{2}(\theta)$ is minimised gives my estimate on parameter $\theta$.

I want to compare this approach to maximum likelihood methods -- partly for fun, and partly to try and get a more intuitive grasp of these methods. However what I can't figure out is what statistic I should be generating with my residuals, $(X_{i} - f(\theta)_{i})$.

Should I still generate $\chi^{2}$ values and then maximise the likelihood function for my set of $\chi^{2}$? Or is a ratio test more appropriate, but then that still leaves the question on what statistic I use to represent a set of residuals for a given parameter?

Answer (score 0):

The first method you describe is the method of least square (given that you have specified the function $f$): find the parameters $\theta$ that minimizes the squared difference between your observations and your model (in your case you say that $f$ only is a function of a parameter $\theta$ and no covariates).

If you want to compare the method of least squares with maximum likelihood you have to pick a distribution for your data $X$ and find the parameter(s) that maximize the likelihood function for your model (if you don't assume a distribution, you can't find the likelihood). One way to do this is to select a distribution and set the parameter value, simulate some data from this model and then see which method that performs the best, i.e. the true parameter.

You write: "Should I still generate $\chi^2$ values and then maximise the likelihood function for my set of $\chi^2$?"  You can of course give in different values of $\theta$ and pick the one that minimize/maximize the squared error/likelihood, but a better option is to find the minimum/maximum by taking the derivative of the squared error/likelihood, setting it equal to zero and solve it wrt $\theta$. This way you know that you have actually found the minimum/maximum.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I *think* I follow, but do you think you could construct a small example?

Comment: What do you actually mean by $f(\theta)$? If you don't have any covariates, what is the reason you have a function of the parameter and not just the parameter?